# Contact Storage is not cleared after deleting the account

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts

I'm writing service to sync contacts with my web service.

I add my account via Account settings. Then I sync it with my web service. Everything is OK. There are no any account on my device before I add my custom account. And Contact Storage app on device has "Data" value as 0.00B.

After syncing, all my contacts appears in Contacts app. Contact Storage app no has "Data" value as 4.53Mb.

Then I remove my account from my device. Contact Storage app now shows "Data" value as 3.74Mb.

After that I re add my account and start to sync it again. After sync if finished, Contact Storage app shows "Data" value ad 7.90Mb.

If I repeat previous steps Contact Storage app "Data" value continues growing.

So why is that? Seems like avatars which I download from my web service doesn't get clean.

How to remove them when I remove my account?

I add avatars like that:

```
public ContactOperations addAvatar(String avatarUrl) {
    contentValues.clear();
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(avatarUrl)) {
        try {
            byte[] avatar = NetworkUtils.downloadAvatar(avatarUrl);
            byte[] resizedAvatar = resizeBitmap(avatar);
            avatar = null;
            contentValues.put(Photo.PHOTO, resizedAvatar);
            contentValues.put(Photo.MIMETYPE, Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
            addInsertOperation();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(ContactOperations.class.toString(), e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }

    return this;
}

private void addInsertOperation() {
    ContentProviderOperation.Builder builder = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI);
    builder.withValueBackReference(StructuredName.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0);
    builder.withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    builder.withValues(contentValues);
    batchOperation.add(builder.build());
}
```

And after that I call method on BatchOperation class

```
public List<Uri> execute() {
    List<Uri> resultUris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

    if (mOperations.size() == 0) {
        return resultUris;
    }
    // Apply the mOperations to the content provider
    try {
        ContentProviderResult[] results = mResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,
                mOperations);
        if ((results != null) && (results.length > 0)){
            for (int i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                resultUris.add(results[i].uri);
            }
        }
    } catch (final OperationApplicationException e1) {
        Log.e(TAG, "storing contact data failed", e1);
    } catch (final RemoteException e2) {
        Log.e(TAG, "storing contact data failed", e2);
    }
    mOperations.clear();
    return resultUris;
}
```